# How install amarok in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, kde-4, amarok

I follow the instructions on amarok.kde.org but doesn't work, any sugestions? likns? the phonon backend dont find vlc

Answer (score 1):

Did you [set an environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) to the VLC installation directory(`C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC` on my machine) as suggested in the [post install instructions](http://amarok.kde.org/wiki/Download:Windows#Post_installation)?